# What does it mean for 20th Century philosophers to lose 'touch with the great thinkers of the past'?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

<sub>Source: p 232, *A Little History of Philosophy* (2011 ed; not 2012 Reprint ed.) by Nigel Warburton [PhD in Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Warburton).</sub>

> For much of the twentieth century philosophers **had lost
>   touch with** the great thinkers of the past. Rawls’ *Theory of Justice*
>   was one of the very few works of political philosophy written in
>   that century that are worth mentioning in the same breath as
>   those by Aristotle, Hobbes, Locke, Rousseau, Hume and Kant.

A novice, I am probably years away from capacitating myself to comment on 20th Century philosophy. So what does the bolded mean exactly? That the 20th Century philosophers became too abstract and theoretical, and not applied or practical? Or worse in quality?

Comment: One example: Sense data theories. They evolved, flourished and were shown to be complete nonsense considering kantian insights by Sellars. But I cannot think of many philosophers that have systematically developed an idea that had any impact outside their own branch of philosophy, never mind outside of philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

I think like everything phylosophy also has evoloved over time. But never was apart from ancient philosophical methods , ways and thoughts. If you look carefully you will understand that 20th century philosophers done the same thing as old onces , most of the ideas already were their in past nothing new. Many old ,ancient philosophers applied same abstract concepts, long theoratical doctrine to prove or to explain things. I think honestely nothing has changed since ancient times. Only every new generation looks at everything freashly and asdume that it has changed a lot, but actually not. So what 20th century philosophers done was already have been done by many old and ancient or medivral philosophers. But over time our understanding of universe has changed a lot ,so these people started to work in accordance with science and tried new expriments in new ways, but with no garbage , thats why we feel it abstract, and non practical. Because it is full of science and that stuff wich is very dificult to follow after centuries of old methods and thunkings